# Office for MAC: open Word Document out of Excel over VBA

Tags: excel, vba, macos, ms-word

I stuck into a stupid error within my VBA code.

situation: create a Word Document out of Excel with a Word Template

problem: the Word Document does not open every time

If Word is still open (but in background) the code works fine.

If Word is closed the code opens Word but not the Document.
Word is open and active in the "new Document" section.
Var wrdDoc (in my code) is empty.
After this first try I close Word and run the code again it works completely fine.
This two steps I can repeat permanently. Only in the second run with a closed Word it works fine.

Before and after the code I have some other thinks, but that could not affect the Word Document.

System: MacBook Pro, macOS Mojave (10.14.2), Microsoft for Mac Version 16.20

Normally the arguments "NewTemplate:=True, Visible:=True" are not needed, but without them the document does not appear in any try.

```
Dim wrdDoc, wrdApp
On Error Resume Next
Set wrdApp = GetObject(, "word.application") 'gives error 429 if Word is not open
If Err = 429 Then
    Set wrdApp = CreateObject("word.application") 'creates a Word application
    Err.Clear
End If
wrdApp.Visible = True
Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.documents.Add(template:="/<path>/template.dotx", _
    NewTemplate:=True, Visible:=True)
```